# Read data from BLE in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cllocationmanager, core-bluetooth

I have a problem with reading data from BLE device in background. Every 30 seconds I must ask my device for data and save it in database. Unfortunately Timer is not working in background so I tried to use CLLocationManager and update location every 30 second and then read value from device. It is working pretty well but not always. When I leave app in the foreground and wait until it will enter background automatically after certain period of time, location manager doesn't work and I don't know why.

Is there any solution to read data every 30 seconds from device when app is in the background?

Comment: Short answer; no. There is no time based background execution on iOS. If you aren’t releasing for the App Store you can use audio background mode and play “silence”.

Comment: Thanks for response! Application will be on app store so it seems that the only way is to modify peripheral functionality.

Comment: Yes. FWIW you would probably get rejected for misusing location services anyway if you don't have a valid reason to use location, and the user can always deny background location use anyway. Polling is rarely a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can let the peripheral notify the central every 30 seconds. Then if you have implemented State preservation and restoration correctly, iOS should wake up your app so you can handle the notifications.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change peripheral functionality. Device notify only when one of the parameters changed. In this case my app doesn't have problems with getting value and saving it into database.

Comment: I'm not into the details of your use case but wouldn't it in that case be better to simply store it whenever it has changed instead of every 30 seconds?